# Creating an Access Form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am not going to pretend to know anything about creating forms in Access, it is an entirely new concept to me. I have a DB in access that contains a number of tables and queries. I would like to create an access form that I can use as a search form, to look up any particular fields i need. I would simply type in what I was looking for and a list of the tables/queries that relate to it would appear. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question "is this doable" is: yes this is absolutely doable.

A good place to start would be to use the Form Wizard. Then get some training (plenty online) on how to design forms. Dlookup will likely be your friend.

Alternatively, a Report is another way to show a specific record based on some specified criteria (show me address for person A).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer Answer: I dont know what your background is. If this is your first Database project then you have a lot of reading to do and I would go and get myself a good ACCESS book and read it or spend a lot of time on the Microsoft Technet.  Thats about as specific as I can get from the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution for you:

Step A: Create a form

There are many ways to create forms. You may try this one:

1) In the Access Objects Window (far left on your screen) mark the table or query you want your form be based on. That means: the form shall display all the fields that are in that specific table or query.

2) With your table or query marked, in the "Create" pane of the Ribbon, click the button "Form". This creates a rudimentary form with all the fields from your table or query arranged in a more or less sensible way. (If you do not like the way the fields are arranged, you can re-arrange them, resize them or remove some of them, etc.)

3) Close this form. On closing, you will be asked to enter a name for it so that you can identify it later.

Step B: Use the form for filtering

1) Open that form (now in "form" view, not "design" view, of course)

2) In Home section of the Ribbon, in the Sort&Filter Area, click on the tiny button "Advanced", and from the dropdown select "Filter by form". Having this done, you then can enter various criteria in the fields on your form. Some of them may display dropdowns to choose from existing content. In some fields you may want to enter stuff like

```
Like "*liv*"
```

which will search for content containing any of live, lively, oblivious, olive, etc.

3) To apply the filtering, in the Ribbon, Home Section, Sort&Filter Area, click "Toggle filter". This will make your form display only records that comply with your criteria.

4) To wipe out your filter criteria, use the button Advanced --> Clear all filters.

This was a very basic introduction into core functionality of Access. Generally, I would support the other contributors here in saying: go to your local library and take any of the various Access introductory books they have there, read it, and try out what you read. You will make quick progress. (You may as well read any tutorial in the internet, but I personally would recommend a book: you just will have the fun to stroll through the pages, perhaps sitting in your garden, and bump into interesting stuff you probably would not have expected. That will help your progress considerably.)